# Chat does not appear in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, sidebar

The chat doesn't seem to appear in the sidebar on the main site (although it does on Meta). [ManishEarth](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31768/manishearth) has suggested that this might be due to the no-ads agreement. I think it would be useful to have it appear in the sidebar, because right now I think its visibility is too low.

Comment: It is at least linked there now, but there was an ad for English.SE; I thought we weren't going to get cross-site ads.

Comment: Hmm, seems inconsistent. I was looking at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94354/essential-reads-in-the-philosophy-of-mathematics-and-set-theory

Comment: And now, looking on my laptop (Firefox, Mountain Lion) instead of my phone (Opera Mini, ICS), I don't get the English.SE ad or the link to chat.

Comment: I'll add that there seems to be the same problem again - but most likely for completely different reasons than 5 years ago: [Chatroom links disappeared](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3611).